# Can I connect a SATA II SSD to my mainboard?

Tags: ssd, sata

I have the next mainboard:

Intel Desktop Board DX38BT - Mainboard – ATX - iX38 – LGA775 Socket – UDMA 100, Serial ATA 300 (RAID), eSATA – Gigabit Ethernet – Firewire – High definition audio (8 Channels)

I want to buy a [Crucial M225 128GB 2.5" SATA-II SSD](http://overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=HD-003-CR&tool=3). Can I connect this new hard disk to the mainboard or this SATA II interface is not compatible?

Currently I have a:

WD Raptor WD1500 AHFD - Hard disk – 150 Gb intern 3.5” –10000 rpm buffer 16 Mb

Comment: Just for info - SATA II only means it supports speeds up to 3 Gb/s but it's in fact SATA disk. You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same disk and it has normal SATA connectors. The only thing is that it has 2.5" casing so you will need adapter to mount it in the PC HDD slot.

Comment: How is it the SSD Disk? Recommend it?

Comment: I have an Antec Performance One P182 case. I think I could mount it with additional adapter.

Comment: Yes, I'm very satisfied. As for adapters, just look for 2.5 to 3.5" disk adapter, costs around 3-5 $.